# Source for Higher Infant Mortality Rates in the Winter of a Leap Year?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, death, rosh-chodesh-new-month, shovavim-tat

At the shiva for my infant son, someone said that the reason we say kaparat pesha in mussaf rosh chodesh, is that to atone for the sins that cause higher rates of stillbirth, miscarriages, and infant deaths in the winter of a leap year.

I have tried to find a source for this.
The Levush (תרפ”ה) says that Shovavim Tat was established because of stillbirth and miscarriages in leap years. Olam Hatefilla by Rav E Munk on the words Kaparat Pesha quotes the Levush and adds in the name of "Acherim" about infant death.

I am looking for the WHO the "Acherim" are/is and also any additional sources on this topic.

(In the two months since my son went to Shomayim, i know of at least 9-10 infant deaths in the Greater Jerusalem Area alone!!)

Comment: Sorry to hear. Statistically, it does not hold, though, see here https://tradingeconomics.com/israel/mortality-rate-infant-per-1-000-live-births-wb-data.html

Comment: Easy to prove your point - in a regular year there are 6 months of winter (Tishrey - Nissan), in a leap year there are 7 months. If the rate is 2/1000 and 1000 births per month there would be 2*6=12 incidents in a regular winter vs 14 incidents in a leap winter. Seems logical.

Comment: @AlBerko I think it means greater then usual per month/1000 births/something else like that, and not more deaths between sukos and pesach bec i doubbt they would establish bec of that

Comment: In my personal experience, it is a very dangerous thing - to validate various pseud-scientifical Rabbinical statements on the correlation between spiritual and physical things. Once revealed and verified, it becomes obsolete. Similar to בחנוני נא בזאת - "those who give charity will become rich" promise - Haredi people are the first in Tzedakah and las in standards of living.

Comment: Very very sorry to hear about your terrible loss. Regarding the last part of your question, there is a well known effect (called Baader Meinhoff) that you start to see events after they happened to you as you suddenly notice things that you didn't notice as much before, see e.g., [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/153166)

Comment: @mbloch I agree that I have noticed infant deaths "more"; I dont think I noticed it at all before; -but I have gone around infant sections of Har Hamenuchot, and although I have not made a scientific study, it does seem that winters of leap years have more deaths. I guess the next time I go I'll write down all the dates in 2-4 sections and plot them by year/season. It also could be that they are more noticeable becouse they are rows of 4-8 graves that all have the same year

Comment: @AlBerko I looked at your link and I fail to see how it disproves my question. The data only shows that TOTAL infant mortality over the ENTIRE year has gone down over the time of the data. It does not differentiate between the jewish and non jewish population, nor time of year. I also object to your opinion that Chareidi people are last in standard of living, they do not have the same values as the secular/MO world, and as a whole do not consider themselves living on a low standard. Your interpretation of rich may not be what they consider Wealth.

Comment: @AlBerko when they talk about first in tzedaka correlated with standard of living they usually mean first in giving tzedaka. The Charedi world is first in taking tzedaka. That'll explain why their standard of living is so low. They can only convince regular Jews with jobs to give them so much money for free.

Comment: @AlBerko Who talks about charity there?? It is about the maaser, the dime from the recolt. Where did you take this "those who give charity become rich"??